# Duplicated @types in typescript libs (index.d.ts - Duplicate identifier) for jasmine, jasminewd2, mocha

Tags: angular, typescript, .d.ts

I've got `jasmine`, `jasminewd2` and `mocha` in my Angular project. Those libs have `index.d.ts` files which seems to be duplicated. Is it some way to avoid this error? Since my Visual Studio cannot build it. I was already trying to exclude those files in my `tsconfig.json` file, upgrading version ain't helping as well.

```
6>C:\GIT\proj\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts(20,18): error TS2300: Build:Duplicate identifier 'describe'.
6>C:\GIT\proj\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts(22,18): error TS2300: Build:Duplicate identifier 'xdescribe'.
6>C:\GIT\proj\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts(31,18): error TS2300: Build:Duplicate identifier 'it'.
6>C:\GIT\proj\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts(41,18): error TS2300: Build:Duplicate identifier 'xit'.
6>C:\GIT\proj\node_modules\@types\jasminewd2\index.d.ts(10,18): error TS2300: Build:Duplicate identifier 'it'.
6>C:\GIT\proj\node_modules\@types\jasminewd2\index.d.ts(12,18): error TS2300: Build:Duplicate identifier 'xit'.
6>C:\GIT\proj\node_modules\@types\mocha\index.d.ts(36,13): error TS2300: Build:Duplicate identifier 'describe'.
6>C:\GIT\proj\node_modules\@types\mocha\index.d.ts(37,13): error TS2300: Build:Duplicate identifier 'xdescribe'.
6>C:\GIT\proj\node_modules\@types\mocha\index.d.ts(42,13): error TS2300: Build:Duplicate identifier 'it'.
6>C:\GIT\proj\node_modules\@types\mocha\index.d.ts(43,13): error TS2300: Build:Duplicate identifier 'xit'.
6>C:\GIT\proj\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts(20,18): error TS2300: Build:Duplicate identifier 'describe'.
6>C:\GIT\proj\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts(22,18): error TS2300: Build:Duplicate identifier 'xdescribe'.
6>C:\GIT\proj\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts(31,18): error TS2300: Build:Duplicate identifier 'it'.
6>C:\GIT\proj\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts(41,18): error TS2300: Build:Duplicate identifier 'xit'.
6>C:\GIT\proj\node_modules\@types\jasminewd2\index.d.ts(10,18): error TS2300: Build:Duplicate identifier 'it'.
6>C:\GIT\proj\node_modules\@types\jasminewd2\index.d.ts(12,18): error TS2300: Build:Duplicate identifier 'xit'.
6>C:\GIT\proj\node_modules\@types\mocha\index.d.ts(36,13): error TS2300: Build:Duplicate identifier 'describe'.
6>C:\GIT\proj\node_modules\@types\mocha\index.d.ts(37,13): error TS2300: Build:Duplicate identifier 'xdescribe'.
6>C:\GIT\proj\node_modules\@types\mocha\index.d.ts(42,13): error TS2300: Build:Duplicate identifier 'it'.
6>C:\GIT\proj\node_modules\@types\mocha\index.d.ts(43,13): error TS2300: Build:Duplicate identifier 'xit'.
```

Comment: Have you tried this?  https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3880

Comment: I saw this and actually there is no solution. Except update dependencies what I already did.

Comment: I would try to run TypeScript compiler with --noLib flag. more here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Comment: @JimiPajala `noLib: true` cannot be used with `lib: ["es2017", "dom"]` which I have in tsconfig.json, anyway it seems that `skipLibCheck: true` helped. I need to make a few more tests to ensure that it didn't broke anything though.

Comment: @DiPix sorry was meant to mention exactly about `skipLibCheck`, great you got it solved! `skipLibCheck` should just work as not checking typings of your npm-modules which could be possible solution in this case. Otherwise it does not introduce any breaking changes to your development/production code.

Comment: And so to say it skips declaration file `.d.ts` file checks on compile time, you'll still get the TypeScript benefits on VSCode or an IDE that you are using.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to JimiPajala we have solution.

I've added `"skipLibCheck": true,` to tsconfig.json

Regarding to documentation:
"*Skip type checking of all declaration files (*.d.ts).*"
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Comment: I had this exact problem, this suggestion did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer might work for many, but did not for me (or at least not as single step).

Influenced by this [comment](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3518#issuecomment-266446573), uninstalling either `@types/jasmine` or `@types/mocha` helps, as their type definitions are conflicting.